# DataGrid Combobox SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatable, datagrid

I've written a simple example in which a `DataGrid` on a WPF form is populated entirely from the codebehind.  A `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ComboBox` has the `ItemsSource` set to a `DummyClass` that contains two properties for the `DisplayMember` and the `SelectedValue`.

A `DataTable` is populated with a single `column` with two `rows`.  The `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid` is set to the default view of the `DataTable`.

When the code runs, each `ComboBox` in the `DataGrid` displays correctly and has the proper options available in the `dropdown` but does not display the values from the `DataTable`.

What binding am I missing to connect the `ComboBox` `SelectedValue` to the values from the `DataTable`?

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public class DummyClass
    {
        public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
        public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DummyClass> DummyClassCollection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DummyClassCollection = new ObservableCollection<DummyClass>();

        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { DisplayValue = "Item1", SelectedValue = 0 });
        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { DisplayValue = "Item2", SelectedValue = 1 });
        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { DisplayValue = "Item3", SelectedValue = 2 });

        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory control = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));

        control.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, DummyClassCollection);
        control.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "DisplayValue");            

        //
        //Some binding to connect ComboBox Selectedvalue to DataTable values
        //

        dataTemplate.VisualTree = control;
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
        templateColumn.Header = "DummyColumn";            
        dgGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("DummyColumn");
        table.Rows.Add(1);
        table.Rows.Add(2);

        dgGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is all you need...

```
        control.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "DisplayValue");
        control.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "SelectedValue");
        control.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, new Binding("DummyColumn"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Adding your 2nd line however does not result with the ComboBox displaying a value once the program runs.  The ComboBoxes still start blank.

Comment: That's it!  Greatly appreciated.